# Is it possible to use JSONPath in Azure App Service Settings

Tags: azure

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that is published to Microsoft Azure.

In the Azure GUI you can add Application Settings.

[image]

I am wondering if it possible to use JSON Path expression in here as using the indexers seems risky to me.

Here is the relevant part of my appsettings.json

> "ConversionTypes": [
> {
> "Name": "convert/word",
> "SupportedExtensions": ".doc,.docx,.rtf,.odt"
> },
> {
> "Name": "convert/excel",
> "SupportedExtensions": ".xls,.xlsx,.ods"
> }
> ]
> }

This is what I tried, which was unsuccessful. This is successful in a JSON Path visualiser. I use this programmatically using the IOptions principles.

> ConversionTypes[?(@['Name']=='convert/excel')]:SupportedExtensions

Answer (score 0):

Can use this conversion tool on Nuget [dotnet-appsettings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-appsettings/). It is required .NET 3.1 SDK. This tool also support array convertion.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-appsettings
dotnet tool list --global
Usage: appsettings [appsettings.json]
```

From `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConversionTypes": [
    { "Name": "convert/word", "SupportedExtensions": ".doc,.docx,.rtf,.odt" },
    { "Name": "convert/excel", "SupportedExtensions": ".xls,.xlsx,.ods" }
  ]
}
```

To:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ConversionTypes__0__Name",
    "value": "convert/word",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ConversionTypes__0__SupportedExtensions",
    "value": ".doc,.docx,.rtf,.odt",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ConversionTypes__1__Name",
    "value": "convert/excel",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ConversionTypes__1__SupportedExtensions",
    "value": ".xls,.xlsx,.ods",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

Same to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67973757/3737294)