# Azure App Service - App Settings Array In Array

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am currently trying to create a "complex" appsettings structure in the Azure App Service configurations and I am failing.

My appsettings.json looks sth. like that:

```
{
"AgentPools": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "PoolName1",
      "AllowedProjects": []
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Name": "PoolName2",
      "AllowedProjects": [
        "myproject1",
        "myproject2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is now, that it seems like that I´m doing sth wrong in the settings for that array in the array.

The configuration looks like that in Azure App Service (Linux):

- AgentPools__0__Id -> 1 => working
- AgentPools__0__Name -> PoolName1 => working

---

- AgentPools__1__Id -> 2 => working
- AgentPools__1__Name -> Poolname2 => working
- AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__0 -> myproject1 => not working
- AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__1 -> myproject2 => not working

---

Am I actually doing something wrong, or is it not even possible to build a somewhat more complex structure?

I´m programming in netcore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables-1) suggest that you can overwrite array values only if the array has objects as nested properties, not values directly.

> When the element structure includes an array, the array index should be treated as an additional element name in this path.

```
{
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.example.com",
    "Logging": [
        {
            "Name": "ToEmail",
            "Level": "Critical",
            "Args": {
                "FromAddress": "MySystem@example.com",
                "ToAddress": "SRE@example.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "ToConsole",
            "Level": "Information"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
setx SmtpServer smtp.example.com
setx Logging__0__Name ToEmail
setx Logging__0__Level Critical
setx Logging__0__Args__FromAddress MySystem@example.com
setx Logging__0__Args__ToAddress SRE@example.com
setx Logging__1__Name ToConsole
setx Logging__1__Level Information
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Can use [the tool (require .NET SDK)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-appsettings/) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67973757/3737294) for help conversion to many formats of environment appsettings (Azure App Service / Configuration, docker-compose).
2. Your appsettings.json when convert to environment will look like below. Then it seems that the way you retrieve values from Configuration may not correct.

```
AgentPools__0__Id
1

AgentPools__0__Name
PoolName1

AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__0
myproject1

AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__1
myproject2

AgentPools__1__Id
2

AgentPools__1__Name
PoolName2
```

3. The easy way to extract Configuration is define class configuration and bind it as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-an-array). Configuration binding array could be either array or list etc

```
internal class AgentPoolsConfig
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string[] AllowedProjects { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
}

internal class AppConfig
{
    public AgentPoolsConfig[] AgentPools { get; set; } = Array.Empty<AgentPoolsConfig>();
}

var agentPools = configuration.GetSection("AgentPools").Get<AgentPoolsConfig[]>() ?? Array.Empty<AgentPoolsConfig>();

var appConfig = configuration.Get<AppConfig>();
```

4. Can debug with environment using `launchSettings.json`

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "AgentPools__1__Id": "2",
        "AgentPools__0__Id": "1",
        "AgentPools__1__Name": "PoolName2",
        "AgentPools__0__Name": "PoolName1",
        "AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__0": "myproject1",
        "AgentPools__1__AllowedProjects__1": "myproject2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

5. How to use the tool

[image: how to use the tool]